# How can I stop Rails execution from initializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, configuration, server, initialization

I want to stop the app start up from an initializer.
Something like if a config isn't present, stop server/console, etc.
Also send a message in order to explain the error.

Is there a way to do that?

I looked into initialization events but I cannot make it happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, just raise an exception like you normally would:

```
raise StandardError, "Stopping app start up because something is missing"
```

If you're doing this because some config is missing, consider using something like Figaro which does this for you.

`Figaro.require_keys("pusher_app_id", "pusher_key", "pusher_secret")`

https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Kernel#abort`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/abort) method to do it. It'll stop the application with your provided message and won't throw up any error.

Example:

```
abort('You need to pass more info to start the application') if some_check_fails?
```